# I create mutil-project template by visual studio , but I want remove the root folder when I create project

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Wzz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtMaL.png)

I want remove the  "CommonProjectTemplate1"  folder, please see the image,  thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Blank Solution in VS:
[image: Blank solution]

then add new project to solution:
[image: New project]

You should get:

[image: VS]

[image: Folder]

Comment: no use , I create the mutil-project template ， then I create project with the project template, the root folder "CommonProjectTemplate1" is created ,  I don't want the root folder  created